# FFmpeg hardware acceleration on Raspberry PI

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, raspberry-pi3, hardware-acceleration

I am building a program that use ffmpeg to stream webcam content over internet. I would like to know if it is possible to use the GPU for the streaming part on the raspberry pi model 3. If yes, how could I implement this on ffmpeg?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need some additional configure options:

- `--enable-mmal` – Enable Broadcom Multi-Media Abstraction Layer (Raspberry Pi) via MMAL. For hardware decoding of H.264, VC-1, MPEG-2, MPEG-4. As a dependency you'll need the *linux-raspberrypi-headers* (Arch Linux) or *linux-headers-*-raspi2* (Ubuntu) package which provides the required header file `mmal.h`.
- `--enable-omx-rpi` – Enable OpenMAX IL code for Raspberry Pi. For hardware encoding of H.264 (encoder is named `h264_omx`) and MPEG-4 (`mpeg4_omx`). As a dependency you'll need the *libomxil-bellagio* (Arch Linux) or *libomxil-bellagio-dev* (Ubuntu) package which provides the required header file `OMX_Core.h`.

For Arch Linux users:

Copy the [PKGBUILD](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD) file for the *ffmpeg* package (perhaps via the [ABS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System) if you prefer). Add the two new configure options shown above, and add the two mentioned packages to the `depends` line. Compile/install with the `makepkg` command.

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I don't have one of these devices to test any of this. Most of this info was acquired from the FFmpeg `configure` file.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

The ffmpeg package from apt now comes with hardware codecs enabled so you can just install that using:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

There are a few hardware enabled codecs on the Pi depending on which model you've got. Here's an excerpt from this detailed [post/thread on the Raspberry Pi Forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=268356#p1628856):

> Pi0-3 have hardware accelerated decode for H264, MPEG4, H263, and
> through optional codec licences for MPEG2 and VC1.
>
> Pi4 has the same hardware accelerated decode for H264, but not the
> other codecs. It also has a separate block for HEVC.

There are a few APIs ([v4l2m2m](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/userspace-api/media/v4l/dev-mem2mem.html), [VAAPI](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/community/vaapi), [OMX](https://www.khronos.org/openmax/), [MMAL](http://www.jvcref.com/files/PI/documentation/html/),...) to access the hardware codecs, but the main one is now the [Video Memory-To-Memory Interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/userspace-api/media/v4l/dev-mem2mem.html) based `h264_v4l2m2m`, and there's also the [older] `h264_omx` OMX based one, and others. For full list of codecs for encode and decode run:

```
ffmpeg -codecs
```

Note: If you have changed the `gpu_mem` setting in `/boot/config.txt` it needs to be greater than 16, otherwise you will get an error with all hardware codecs.