# Pjsip/Pjsua video problem : frame buffer too small

Tags: sip, pjsip, pjsua2, openh264

I try to make a sip video call using Pjsip/Pjsua on my raspberry pi 3.
Before coding, I'm using the main sample app to test different options. Everything seems to work (registering, audio calling,..) but when I try to start a video call, the programs stops with the following message :

> *pjsua-armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf: ../src/pjmedia-videodev/v4l2_dev.c:737: vid4lin_stream_get_frame_mmap: Assertion `!"frame buffer is too small for v4l2"' failed.*

I've searched a lot, including the source code :

```
/* get frame from mmap */
static pj_status_t vid4lin_stream_get_frame_mmap(vid4lin_stream *stream, pjmedia_frame *frame)
{
struct v4l2_buffer buf;
pj_time_val time;
pj_status_t status = PJ_SUCCESS;

pj_bzero(&buf, sizeof(buf));
buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
status = xioctl(stream->fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buf);
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
return status;

if (frame->size < buf.bytesused) {
/* supplied buffer is too small */
pj_assert(!"frame buffer is too small for v4l2");
status = PJ_ETOOSMALL;
goto on_return;
}
```

So I understand that the pjmedia_frame has a "size" inferior to the v4l2 buffer, resulting to my failure.
My question is simple : how can i change this setting ? 
I tried evetything in the sample app : changing resolution, bitrate, fps,..
I found some ressources saying to change the *h264 profile level*.. ok, but where do i set it ? Is it within the v4l2 manager ? or directly in the app  ? How can i do it ?
I played with different options in v4l2 to *reduce* the bitrate/resolution in order to have a small buffer, but still getting the same error.

At this point I'm completely clueless.

For info, I compiled PJsip using openh264 (no libx264) as suggested by PjSip.

Thanks for your help/ideas ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to your question about profile level, you can try with:

```
const pj_str_t codec_id = {"H264", 4};
pjmedia_vid_codec_param param;
pj_status_t status;

status = pjsua_vid_codec_get_param(&codec_id, &param);
param.dec_fmtp.param[0].name = pj_str("profile-level-id");
param.dec_fmtp.param[0].val = pj_str("42e01f");
status = pjsua_vid_codec_set_param(&codec_id, &param);
```

do this anywhere after `pjsua_start()`. Last two characters in `val` property are profile level. Description of levels can be found here ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding#Levels)). More information about h264 profile here ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960928/identify-h264-profile-and-level-from-profile-level-id-in-sdp)).

I'm not an expert of v4l2, but have little experience with encoding video on rpi3, and I suggest you to use FFmpeg instead of pure openh264, beacuse of support of hardware acceleration ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175644/ffmpeg-hardware-acceleration-on-raspberry-pi)).

Good luck!