# (Folderwide) Bulk conversion in ffmpeg to a H264 codec

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, data-conversion, ffprobe

So I was trying to get a hang of ffmpeg but I am not very good at it. I am trying to get all .mkv files converted to .m4v with a H264 codec. From another project I know that the h264_cuvid decoder worked perfectly well for my needs. I also checked via `ffmpeg -decoders` that I wrote it correctly. So the windows-batchfile (I frankenstein-ed together from other forums) looks like this:

```
for %%a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v h264_cuvid -preset fast -crf 20 -b:v 128k "newfiles\%%~na.m4v"
pause
```

What I get is sadly only:

> unknown encoder 'h264_cuvid'

How do I solve this?

**If it is easier to start from scratch following is what I am trying to achieve**

I am pretty new to this whole conversion/coding thing. I got a raspberry pi as a homeserver for my video files. Sadly it can only direct stream correctly encoded files (H.264), otherwise the Pi is trying to encode the videos itself (what causes buffering). So I am trying to find a solution to throw my whole library into a folder and convert it to a usable format.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use another codec because the h264_cuvid is strictly related to NVIDIA CUDA, and it doesn't run on Raspberri Pi of course. In order to use h264_cuvid, you need an NVIDIA GPU with the HW codec. See https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk/download for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

## Just re-mux if you can

Do the `.mkv` files already contain H.264 or another format supported by `.m4v`? If yes, then you can just [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) the video with `-c:v copy` and not have to re-encode:

```
for %%a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v copy "newfiles\%%~na.m4v"
pause
```

---

## h264_cuvid is a decoder

It is **not** an encoder, and Raspberry does not support CUVID anyway. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Hardware](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro).

---

## If you must encode

#### Use libx264

```
for %%a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 20 -b:v 128k "newfiles\%%~na.m4v"
pause
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.

#### Or h264_omx for hardware accelerated encoding

If your Raspberry and `ffmpeg` supports OpenMax you can use h264_omx:

```
for %%a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v h264_omx "newfiles\%%~na.m4v"
pause
```

- You need your `ffmpeg` to be compiled with `--enable-omx --enable-omx-rpi` to use this.
- It is a simple and limited encoder compared to libx264 so results will not be as good.
- See [FFmpeg hardware acceleration on Raspberry PI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40182218/).

#### h264_mmal for hardware accelerated decoding

If your `ffmpeg` was compiled with `--enable-mmal`, and your Raspberry supports  Broadcom Multi-Media Abstraction Layer, and your input video formats are either H.264, VC-1, MPEG-2, or MPEG-4, then you can also add hardware decoding:

```
for %%a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg -c:v h264_mmal -i "%%a" -c:v h264_omx "newfiles\%%~na.m4v"
pause
```